# Override UIView drawRect to only draw in its rect

Tags: ios, uiview, drawrect

How to force the child views to only draw in the rect of itself?

How can I override the drawRect method or any easy way to do it?
Thanks.

Comment: Missing `clipsToBounds`, are we now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks David for the tip.

I found the "Clip Subviews" property in the Interface builder.